# Why is .append() creating 2 rows in this code when I click Add New button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why is .append() creating 2 identical rows in this code when I click Add New button? I don't see why 2 appends happen. Am I misunderstanding something? This doesn't happen with vanilla javascript but happens with jquery.

I added the table which includes the tbody tag at the end of the table where I would like to append the template string in function onAddProduct(e).
(Note: I removed html since it was an assignment.)

here is the code snippet

```js
$(function() {
  var $formEl  = $('form');
  var $tbodyEl = $('tbody');
  var $tableEl = $('table');

  function onAddProduct(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $pName = $('#pname').val();
    var $pCat = $('#pcat').val();
    var $pPrice = $('#pprice').val();
    $tbodyEl.append(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${$pName}</td>
                    <td>${$pCat}</td>
                    <td>${$pPrice}</td>
                    <td><button class="deleteBtn">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                `);
  }

  function onDeleteRow(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains("deleteBtn")) {
      return;
    }

    const btn = e.target;
    btn.closest("tr").remove();
  }

  //formEl.addEventListener("submit", onAddProduct);
  $formEl.on({
    submit: onAddProduct
  });
  //tableEl.addEventListener("click", onDeleteRow);    
  $tableEl.on({
    click: onDeleteRow
  });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you have 2 tbody's? The code you posted as none, so it adds no new rows - if you add one tbody, it adds 1, if you add 23 tbody elements it adds 23

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is the `table` and the `tbody` element defined? I do not see them in your example. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: **Jaromanda X** is right, your `<table>` is badly formed, it has 2 `<tbody>`, it can be seen in the code inspector (F12 key)

Comment: omg, i see it in the code inspector. thanks!

Comment: the Javascript language has evolved a lot, and browsers now scrupulously respect web standards. which makes jQuery more and more useless, especially since this kind of code does not take more than 20 lines in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var $formEl = $('form');
  var $tbodyEl = $('tbody');
  var $tableEl = $('table');

  function onAddProduct(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", $tableEl));
    $("<td>").html($('#pname').val()).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html($('#pcat').val()).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html($('#pprice').val()).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html("<button class='deleteBtn'>Delete</button>").appendTo(row);
    return;
  }

  function onDeleteRow(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains("deleteBtn")) {
      return;
    }
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Product?")) {
      $(e.target).closest("tr").remove();
    }
  }

  $formEl.on({
    submit: onAddProduct
  });
  
  $tableEl.on({
    click: onDeleteRow
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Add Product</h4><br>
<form>
  <label for="pname">Product Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname">
  <label for="pcat">Product Category:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pcat" name="pcat">
  <label for="pprice">Product price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pprice" name="pprice">
  <button type="submit" class="addBtn">Add New</button>
</form>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Category</th>
      <th>Product Price</th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am not able to replicate the issue with this code. Only 1 Row is added.

Comment: I added the table which includes the tbody tag at the end of the table where I would like to append the template string in function onAddProduct(e).

Answer (score 0):

Your table is missing the `<tbody>` around the rows you have added, so the browser is adding it in to create a valid table. This results in 2 `<tbody>` elements, and is why rows are being added twice:
[image]

It can be prevented by putting the header and body rows inside the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements that the browser wants, seen below in the snippet -

```js
$(function() {
  var $formEl = $('form');
  var $tbodyEl = $('tbody');

  function onAddProduct(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $pName = $('#pname').val();
    var $pCat = $('#pcat').val();
    var $pPrice = $('#pprice').val();
    $tbodyEl.append(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${$pName}</td>
                    <td>${$pCat}</td>
                    <td>${$pPrice}</td>
                </tr>
                `);
  }

  $formEl.on({
    submit: onAddProduct
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="productTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Category</th>
      <th>Product Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>M&M</td>
      <td>Snacks</td>
      <td>$1.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Furniture</td>
      <td>$1.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kale</td>
      <td>Vegetables</td>
      <td>$2.49</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h4>Add Product</h4><br>
<form>
  <label for="pname">Product Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname">
  <label for="pcat">Product Category:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pcat" name="pcat">
  <label for="pprice">Product price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pprice" name="pprice">
  <button type="submit" class="addBtn">Add New</button>
</form>
```